# post request to mediawiki api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to post data to the mediawiki API and it's not recognising the token I am sending.

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
      action: "createaccount",
      name: "sean",
      email: "xxx",
      password: "test",
      token: "66cde5ad831521fe9d0fe4df3a2db25f"
});

var options = {
    host: '54.201.91.132',
    port: 80,
    path: '/wiki/api.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

I have tried sending the same data using the Postman chrome extension and this works fine.

```
POST /wiki/api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 54.201.91.132
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 action=createaccount&name=shamus&email=xxx&password=test&token=5dc9c943ac3255f87dc7782c24f61ac6&format=json

{
"createaccount": {
    "username": "Shamus",
    "userid": 22,
    "token": "c3744c0f19ea62f6baf89b10f7c86f7f",
    "result": "success"
}
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the token from?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to token, you must pass it the cookies you received with it. Of course, the token must not be  hardcoded and be acquired dynamically.